# How to open a create-react-app from another computer connected to the same network?

Tags: node.js, networking, localhost, create-react-app

I am using ***create-react-app*** and hosting in its default port **localhost:3000** and want to access this from another device on the same network.

I got the IP of my host's IP (using *ifconfig*) **192.168.0.5** and tried opening ***192.168.0.5:3000*** but that did not work.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 117):

Simply run `HOST=0.0.0.0 npm run start`.
 
Afterwards open the url from another device on the network.

In your case, `192.168.0.5:3000` would work.

[Documentation](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/docusaurus/docs/advanced-configuration.md) for setting HOST environment variables.

Comment: Solved, If you're using webpack, Open package.json add `--host 0.0.0.0` option to script.start field. Done.

Comment: I just get blank white page, is there a way to debug whats wrong?

Comment: [MacOS] If you don't know your IP, go `System Preferences > Network > Advanced > TCP/IP` and check the IPv4 Address

Comment: how can we replace system IP address to localhost?

Comment: It is better to set HOST=127.0.0.1, because I always get warnings when HOST=0.0.0.0

Comment: How to change port from 3000 to different

Comment: You might not actually need the `HOST=0.0.0.0` part. In my case, running the normal start command (`npm run start`) worked. I was able to see the app on my phone's browser at URL `[My Macbook's IP address]:3000`. I used [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/147777/407739) to find my macbook's IP address. The [docs in your post](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/docusaurus/docs/advanced-configuration.md) mention this default behavior, under the HOST section.

Answer (score 25):

I had the same problem and when I disabled the private firewall it worked for me.

[image]

or if you want to enable private firewall you need to go here:

Control Panel\System and Security\Windows Defender Firewall\Allowed applications

[image]

and enable "change settings" than check private checkbox in Node.js row

[image]

Comment: Thank you, It worked fine. But is there any security issues??

Answer (score 20):

If you are on Ubuntu, simply run

```
$> sudo ufw allow 3000
```

Then access your app using your internal ip from local network.
to get your local IP run:

```
$> ifconfig
```

Comment: What about windows users?

Comment: @wilson382 Add a firewall rule to allow port 3000. To know how to add a firewall rule read https://stackoverflow.com/a/33657331/13163131

Answer (score 17):

As I can't post comment,
In complementary to Elad
if you have `react-scripts start` instead of `npm run start`

`HOST=0.0.0.0 react-scripts start`

Works too !

Answer (score 5):

I am using ubuntu 20.04 and both my android and laptop was connected to same wifi network.

Step 1: in `package.json` set `--host=0.0.0.0` for `server` key.

```json
...

  "scripts": {
    "go": "open http://localhost:3000; npm run server",
    "e2e": "nightwatch --config nightwatch.js",
    "run-e2e": "concurrently -s first -k \"npm start\" \"sleep 15; npm run e2e\"",
    "test": "./node_modules/.bin/concurrently -k 'npm run server' 'npm run e2e'",
    "start": "npm run server",
    "server": "live-server public --host=0.0.0.0 --port=3000 --middleware=./disable-browser-cache.js"
  },

...
```

Step 2: Add rule for port 3000 in ubuntu firewall.

```sh
sudo ufw allow 3000
```

Step 3: Now I can access same react app on

- `http://localhost:3000/`   # desktop
- `http://127.0.0.1:3000/`   # desktop
- `http://192.168.X.X:3000/` # from android and desktop both (replace with your internal IP)

Comment: Does it makes a difference if one is on wifi and the other on cable? Since one is 10.0.0.101 and the other is 10.0.0.107?

Comment: Until both device are on same network cable and wifi is same. Check internal IP (in ubuntu I use `ifconfig` command). If both device can access this internal IP (mine was `192.168.1.5`) then There is no issue. Only possible if cable comes from WiFI router and mobile connected to same WiFi (you case possibly)

Comment: Working as a charm

Answer (score 4):

In my case, `npm run start` used my Ethernet adapter's IP e.g. `http://192.168.167.113:3000` but as I was accessing the site using WLAN, I needed to use WLAN IP which was `192.168.0.227`.

Make sure to use WLAN IP with the same port to make it work.

Answer (score 4):

If you are on windows and the above solutions don't work, it is most probably a firewall issue. You can try looking in Allowed Applications in Control Panel, to check if node is allowed on private networks. Or looking in the Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security and checking the Monitoring\Firewall tab and check for Node.js.

Comment: Also, I found the output of the `npm run start` was printing a misleading IP address. I had to check my ip via `ipconfig` .Once using the proper IP address my issue was resolved.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I had the same problem, But Why do you think npm run starts to print a misleading IP address? I had to change to the correct IP address and it worked

Comment: It totally was! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

at the end of 2021 was doing several react projects via tutorials at that time when i started apps, it was showing 2 links with localhost and ip address link and 2nd link was for devices it the same network. and now (18 may 2022) when i wanted to make react app independently, when i am starting my react app its giving link with localhost. in my case (windows 11) try http://yourComputerIp:portNumber

to get ip on windows type ipconfig in cmd and your ip address will be under name IPv4 Address

Answer (score 1):

if you have two machines (lets say pc1 and pc2) and both are connected over the same wifi connection, then:

- bind your create-react-app development server to your Wireless LAN adapter wi-fi IPv4 address (on windows type the command `ipconfig.exe` and unix-like systems type `ifconfig`).. you will find the ip address under something:
- `Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi` (on windows)
- `wlp5s0` `inet Ip_Address`
- in your sheel where you develop react run `HOST=your_IP npm run start`

now, your development machin will be the server that serves the ui over it's IP_Address

Comment: Thanks this was the only answer that helped me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes there is another problem for Windows users.

Windows Firewall blocks NodeJs.

Just go to Windows Defender Firewall and click to **Allow an app or feature through Windows Defender Firewall** and allow Node.js

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing

> HOST=0.0.0.0 : The term 'HOST=0.0.0.0' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

If I run (without using the npm wrapper script)

```
HOST=0.0.0.0 PORT=8000 ./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start
```

To fix it, go to package.json and changed the "start" script to

```
"start": "./node_modules/.bin/react-scripts start",
```

then add this line of code.

```
"server": "live-server public --host=0.0.0.0 --port=3000 --middleware=./disable-browser-cache.js",
```

Then `npm start` works fine.

more details [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60265154/10094778)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29903415)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. I'll be careful in the future on this.

Answer (score 1):

As someone else already mentioned, it's possible that React is just giving you the wrong IP address. In my case, React was pulling from one of my VMWare ethernet adapters. To open the right one, type `ipconfig` in Command Prompt and use the IPv4 Address listed under "Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi" or your actual ethernet adapter.

Answer (score 0):

My react-scripts:3.4.1 is working,

from

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start"
}
```

to ( 0.0.0.0 is not work )

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "HOST=127.0.0.1 react-scripts start"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After running `npm start` go to your terminal "bash, cmd ..etc" and run `ipconfig`

IPv4-Adresse ..... : for example 111.222.333.444

open browser in your second device and type : 111.222.333.444:portNumber

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Windows Firewall blocked port 3000. So adding an Inbound Rule to open port 3000 did the trick.

Windows Defender Firewall with Advanced Security > Inbound Rules > New Rule...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows then

1. run this `echo ((ipconfig | findstr [0-9].\.)[0]).Split()[-1]` on your powershell or directly on the vscode terminal.
2. then do **npm start** and access your react-app using the ip shown by the above step ( yourIp:port , e.g. 192.168.8.100:3000)

Answer (score 0):

Step:1 - In webpack.config.js change host to "host: '0.0.0.0'",
Step:2 - npm run start,
Step:3 - run ipconfig and replace your ipv4 with http://192.168.X.X:3000,

In case it won't work add allow Nodejs in firewall and add Inbound rule with port 3000

Comment: Please provide an explanation of your answer so that the next user knows why this solution worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using an azure VM make sure you add an inbound rule to allow traffic for port 3000
you can do this by

1. go to your deployed VM
2. go to networking
3. and add an Allow inbound rule for port 3000

Answer (score 0):

if you are on windows ,please turn off your firewall and replace your  address on the phone  with  the Wireless lan adapter WIFI ipv4 address  which you can find it easily by typing `ipconfig` on PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

You must connect the same network while serving with other systems, then you can simply enter:

```bash
npm start HOST="current_ip_address"
```

(ex: 191.161.221.209) and share the `ip_address` with port number

Answer (score 0):

```
npm run start --host=0.0.0.0
```

You can try using the host value using the flag and  once compiled, yu will get the url to access within the network and local as well

Answer (score -1):

Can you please turn off your firewall and check 192.168.0.5:3000.

Thanks

Comment: This is not correct as provided IP might be correct for you but not for others depending on whe WAN ip address