# create react app - access "On your network" doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, networking, create-react-app

I'm using create-react-app project. I try to test my localhost:3000 app on my iphone.

When I start an app `yarn start` I get this message:

> Compiled successfully!
>
> You can now view front-client in the browser.
>
> Local:            http://localhost:3000/   On Your Network: 
>   http://172.20.10.5:3000/

But when I go to http://172.20.10.5:3000/ the browser window just spins and nothing happens.

I have the firewall on my mac set off.

I also tried setting host to 0.0.0.0 like they suggest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47412363/how-to-open-a-create-react-app-from-another-computer-connected-to-the-same-netwo) but it didn't work:

> $ HOST=0.0.0.0 NODE_PATH=src react-scripts start Attempting to bind to
>   HOST environment variable: 0.0.0.0 If this was unintentional, check
>   that you haven't mistakenly set it in your shell. Learn more here:
>   https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/advanced-configuration

What might be the reason that I cannot access this app on my network?
Is there any other way to test it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that I had Eset Security filtering incoming requests:

[image]

Disabling it fixed the problem.