# React - upload an image to Imgur using axios returns ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, wysiwyg, draftjs

I'm trying to send POST request to Imgur API - to upload an image.

My Imgur App is public - only Client ID is required.

Always getting this error during runtime:

> Error: Network Error
> at createError (createError.js:16)
> at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:84) "POST https://api.imgur.com/3/image net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR"

It's working when I send the request manually (using Postman).
[Postman success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6Vwu.png)

**Setup:**

- Local Development on WSL2 - Ubuntu 20.04LTS
- React
- react-draft-wysiwyg

**My editor:**

```
<Editor
        editorState={content}
        onEditorStateChange={(e) => setContent(e)}
        wrapperClassName="demo-wrapper"
        editorClassName="demo-editor"
        toolbar={{
          image: {
            uploadCallback: uploadImageCallBack,
            alt: { present: true, mandatory: false },
          },
        }}
 />
```

**Upload functions I've tried.**

Attempt #1 - axios implementation

```
function uploadImageCallBack(file) {
  return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append("image", file);
    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: "Client-ID xxx",
      },
    };
    axios.post("https://api.imgur.com/3/image", data, config).then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      resolve()
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
      reject()
    });
  });
}
```

Attempt #2 - XHR Implementation from Documentation
https://github.com/jpuri/react-draft-wysiwyg/blob/master/stories/ImageUpload/index.js

```
function uploadImageCallBack(file) {
  return new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); // eslint-disable-line no-undef
      xhr.open('POST', 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image');
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Client-ID xxx');
      const data = new FormData(); // eslint-disable-line no-undef
      data.append('image', file);
      xhr.send(data);
      xhr.addEventListener('load', () => {
        const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        resolve(response);
      });
      xhr.addEventListener('error', () => {
        const error = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        reject(error);
      });
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Try adding a header of `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` it looks like the browser is stopping the request because something like the content type or length, etc doesn't match. I could be server side too, but would start client side diagnosing

Comment: Hello,

Unfortunately this didn't fix my issue. The problem was WSL itself. See comment below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out this issue.

Ref: [Imgur api responding with code 403 with server error 429](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66195106/imgur-api-responding-with-code-403-with-server-error-429)

This solution worked out perfectly.
Imgur blocks all requests from localhost.

Although due to the WSL networking, you wont't be able to access server at 0.0.0.0.

Solution for WSL Ubuntu:

```
hostname -I
```

Create .env file next to the package.json.

```
HOST=<output from hostname -I>
```