# Receive error429 from GET request Imgur API

Tags: typescript, next.js, axios, imgur, http-status-code-429

I am getting a `Request failed with status code 429` from `Imgur API` while my `Client_ID`  is new and I haven't even used it,

here is my Api.ts:

```
const imgurClientId = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_Client_ID

const BASE = "https://api.imgur.com/3";
const EP_GALLERY = `${BASE}/gallery`;
const EP_GALLERY_TAGS = `${BASE}/tags`;


 async function imgurBaseApi(args: Args) {
    const myHeaders = new Headers({
      Authorization: `Client-ID ${imgurClientId}`,
    });

    args.requestOptions = {
      ...args.requestOptions,
      headers: myHeaders,
      method: "GET",
    };

    const response = await fetch(args.endPoint, args.requestOptions);
    const responseJson = await response.json();

    return responseJson.data;
  }


// how I use it:
  async function getGalleryTagMetadata(requestArgs: TypeState["requestArgs"]) {
    const endPoint = `${EP_GALLERY}/t/${requestArgs.tagName}/${requestArgs.sort}/${requestArgs.window}/${requestArgs.page}`;

    return imgurBaseApi({ endPoint: endPoint });
  }
```

I also tried it with simple `fetch` call like this:

```
  const imgurClientId = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_Client_ID

  const sort = 'viral'
  const window = 'day'
  const page = 1

  const url = `https://api.imgur.com/3/gallery/search/${sort}/${window}/${page}?q=cats`

  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: new Headers({
      Authorization: `Client-ID ${imgurClientId}`,
    }),
  }

  fetch(url, requestOptions)
    .then((response) => {
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`)
      }
      return response.json()
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log('dta', data)
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error:', error)
    })
```

I have followed the [Imgur documentation](https://apidocs.imgur.com/#intro) to set up my `Client_ID` and when I tried it with Postman it worked fine with a successful `GET` request.

My question:

As this is an application just to receive some images, do I need to go through the 0auth2 steps?

ps. The complete code is longer, but let me know and I will print it here

Thanks in advance

cheers
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I changed my start script in package.json to this "start": "react-scripts start --host 0.0.0.0" based on a comment [someone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66209846/19390997) mentioned here. Then I point my browser at http://0.0.0.0:3000/ and I'm able to get a response from imgur.

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is a [source address only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3655736/283366). It would also have no bearing on your use of the imgur API. [429 Too Many Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429) can only clear when your request rate drops below the threshold set by the API