# Why cant I access my react app from another device?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

So im trying to access my React web application with ipadress and the portnumber 3000. I tried from another computer and from another phone. But the webpage keeps on loading and then tells me it can't reach the website. Why not?
Here is the github link for my project:
https://github.com/darja2001/collaborative-whiteboard-SR

Comment: Try disabling firewall, bind to IP address or 0.0.0.0, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47412363/how-to-open-a-create-react-app-from-another-computer-connected-to-the-same-netwo

Answer (score 1):

- Make Sure Your Computer and Phone or computer are connected to same
  network.
- Open command prompt and type ipconfig and Copy Ipv4 address.
- In your phone or another computer open URL http://(Ipv4 adress):(port
  number)

And you will get it
Else you can also use ngrok to access your react app anywhere.