# Cannot access local server using localhost but works via IP

Tags: node.js, reactjs, serverless-offline

I'm viewing a locally hosted website (React ). I can view it via IP http://192.168.1.100:3000/ (192.168.1.100 is my local IP address), but not via http://localhost:3000/ or http://127.0.0.1:3000/

I can access my locally hosted content at http://localhost:5000/ from the node express service, but I cannot access my serverless offline from http://localhost:5050/.

I haven't had this trouble before, it is not working since last week. Do you have any idea what needs to change?

Comment: How are you running the React app? If you want it to bind to all network interfaces, you'll need to use `0.0.0.0:3000`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open a create-react-app from another computer connected to the same network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47412363/how-to-open-a-create-react-app-from-another-computer-connected-to-the-same-netwo). Or this? [How to make the webpack dev server run on port 80 and on 0.0.0.0 to make it publicly accessible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33272967/how-to-make-the-webpack-dev-server-run-on-port-80-and-on-0-0-0-0-to-make-it-publ)

Comment: @Phil I run it as "react-scripts start". It was working well before, just from last week, it is not working.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is the ITS do some updates, and it caused this issue. If you have the same issue, please check any internal policy updates. Some company has some software that may cause the issue.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).