# How to force create-react-app to run 0.0.0.0 to make it publicly accessible

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I need create-react-app to run on 0.0.0.0 on my network. Changing the host ENV or putting CLI arguments in create-react-app doesn't work at all. Is there anyway to do this? I also have a flask server that needed this and adding `host='0.0.0.0'` when using `app.run` easily fixed it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47412363/how-to-open-a-create-react-app-from-another-computer-connected-to-the-same-netwo