# cannot access localhost on mobile

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I am working on a react project. When I run it using npm start I can see the website on my laptop's browser, but when I try to access it via my phone using my local IP i.e 192.168.0.107:3000 , it does not load. The same happened with react native project when I try to open it on my phone using Expo. It just says something went wrong and the site does not open.
I am using windows 11. Could it be an issue with the firewall or is this something else?

Comment: Can you check your firewall configuration?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47412363/13690331)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to open a create-react-app from another computer connected to the same network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47412363/how-to-open-a-create-react-app-from-another-computer-connected-to-the-same-netwo)

Comment: @SyedMainulHasan I had added inbound firewall rules to allow connections on port 3000 but it still does not work.

Comment: @ebarooni I tried this as well. Did not work

Answer (score 0):

I have tried all this and my VScode with react works very well:

1. First I tried to select the default browser from the windows setting.
2. Second I changed the following settings in the Live Server Configuration:
   (a) Settings: Custom Browser set to "chrome" (or a browser that you select default in windows settings)
   (b) Settings: Click/Tick the Local Ip
3. Disable all firewalls from window settings (Domain/Public/Private)

Try all these settings and one of the above will work certainly.